# Docker Compose Pull Multiple 'latest' Images Simultaneously then Tag with New Tag

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to pull multiple latest images simultaneously. I have figured that part out.

`docker compose pull --parallel`

Now I am wondering, is there a way for me to apply a new tag to these 'latest' images? My current docker-compose.yaml is below.

My intention is to pull 'latest' from one repo and apply a new tag for a push to a different repo.

```
services:
  image-1:
    image: imagename1:latest
  image-2:
    image: imagename2:latest
  image-3:
    image: imagename3:latest
  image-4:
    image: imagename4:latest
  image-5:
    image: imagename5:latest
  image-6:
    image: imagename6:latest
  image-7:
    image: imagename7:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

you could be using a bash script with a loop on these images and use `docker tag` command,
See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/

for example:

```bash
images=(imagename1:latest ...)
#
for image in ${images[@]}
do 
    docker tag $image iamgename1:$TAG
done
```